# Send email using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

i want to ask, could i send html email using google apps script, 
where the html file is using localfile or on my website www.abc.tld/htmlbody.html

also the recipient email address is using a txt file not using google spreadsheet

i've search this function over the google, but i didn't find any solution

ps : i've done with phpmailer, but im trying something new using google apps script

```
$provider = new Google(
    [
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
    ]
);
$mail->setOAuth(
    new OAuth(
        [
            'provider' => $provider,
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
            'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
            'userName' => $email,
        ]
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes, use `MailApp` to send the mail. You can request information from other servers with `UrlFetchApp`. Your provided code is not Google Apps Script so it appears you haven't done any research and just asked if something is possible instead of checking yourself first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a working example:

```
function inlineImage() {
  var googleLogoUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png";
  var youtubeLogoUrl = "https://developers.google.com/youtube/images/YouTube_logo_standard_white.png";
  var googleLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                      .fetch(googleLogoUrl)
                      .getBlob()
                      .setName("googleLogoBlob");
  var youtubeLogoBlob = UrlFetchApp
                       .fetch(youtubeLogoUrl)
                       .getBlob()
                       .setName("youtubeLogoBlob");
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "yourmail@gmail.com",
    subject: "Logos",
    htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
           "inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>",
    inlineImages:
      {
        googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
        youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using phpmailer, you can use the variable: 
$mail->isHtml ();
and use the PHP function
file_get_content();
to extract your template made in HTML saved between your folders.

Example:
$mail->MsgHTML(file_get_content ('public_html / templates / mytemplatre.html'));

Comment: yes i already add file_get_contents, my main question is can i do send html email like phpmailer, using google apps scripts sendMail function

Comment: maybe you can use this information https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49933899/7215091) of sending emails with Google Apps Script.